# Partially responding Drupal jQuery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, module, drupal-7, click

I am loading a simple jquery script from a custom Drupal module.

The browser network data confirms my script is successfully loaded but my simple **click** detection attempts go undetected. A **console.log** message does respond but not the functions. My code is below:

```
(function ($) { 
    $('body').click( // unresponsive
        function(){
            alert('responding');
        }
    );

    console.log('Responding'); // this works

    jQuery('input#edit-search').click( // unresponsive
        function(){
            alert('testing ... testing!');
        }
    );
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer.

It seems Drupal 7 prefers the following jquery code format:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
    $('input#edit-search').hide();
});
```